# C# MongoRepository generic call

Tags: c#, generics, mongorepository

I am using the following extension:

https://github.com/RobThree/MongoRepository

I try to create a generic class to manage my repositories.

However, I would like to use a generic class with MongoRepository.

I have the error:

Error   CS0314  The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MongoRepository'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'MongoRepository.IEntity'.

Do you know how I could fix my error?

Thanks!

```
public class DataService<T>
{
    public static Dictionary<Type, MongoRepository<T>> References = new Dictionary<Type, MongoRepository<T>>
    {
        { typeof(EmailTransac), EmailTransacs },
        { typeof(LogException), LogExceptions },
        { typeof(ApplicationUser), Users },
        { typeof(LogActivity), LogActivities },
        { typeof(Referential), Referentials }

    };

    public static MongoRepository<EmailTransac> EmailTransacs { get { return Singleton<MongoRepository<EmailTransac>>.Instance; } }
    public static MongoRepository<LogException> LogExceptions { get { return Singleton<MongoRepository<LogException>>.Instance; } }
    public static MongoRepository<ApplicationUser> Users { get { return Singleton<MongoRepository<ApplicationUser>>.Instance; } }
    public static MongoRepository<LogActivity> LogActivities { get { return Singleton<MongoRepository<LogActivity>>.Instance; } }
    public static MongoRepository<Referential> Referentials { get { return Singleton<MongoRepository<Referential>>.Instance; } }


}
```

Comment: You need a generic constraint on your `T`. Something like `where T : IEntity`.

Answer (score 1):

T needs to implement IEntity.

Try this...

```
public class DataService<T> where T : IEntity
```